# Disable module for MFTF

Tags: mftf

A third-party module, Amasty common tests, breaks the generation of MFTF tests. The reason is the invalid format of some of the provided XML files. I disabled the module using the Magento command but while generating the tests is still using the files, so the generation fails. Is there a way to disable it for MFTF? I was wondering if it can be done in .env but I didn't find something related yet.